# Get currently online users?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

After googling a bit I have found some tips about how to get online Users with ASP.NET.
But I am using my own class for membership.

The information I have found is:

1. Log the users sessionId to database when the user logs in
2. Log them out when their session time out

What is your advice about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this great [article](http://blog.sb2.fr/post/2008/12/01/HowTo-Get-Current-Online-Users-Count-and-Infos-with-ASPNET.aspx)

Hope helps someone

Answer (score 0):

We use this approach at work so that when users upload data in separate but concurrent session to a webservice, we can catch 90% of the cases where timeout has occurred and warn the user then and there.

We don't catch every case because:

- Session timeout event handler in global.asax isn't reliably called the moment expiration occurs (IIRC)
- The user could have closed their browser window in the mean time.

Two common approaches of which I am aware are:

- Any user action causes an update to LastActionTime in the users table. Using this value + 20 minutes (or whatever your session timeout value) is a pretty good indication of who is logged in
- A small AJAX panel updating every few seconds (linked with the previous option).

Comment: Thanks for the great info,
I have found a useful article about the issue
Thanks again