# Number on-line users on ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net

Currently, writing an application in ASP.NET How to calculate and display the main form of on-line users or the number of running Web sites if run on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally store an application variable and then in your global increment / decrement on session start / session end respectively.

Failing that, this is an even better approach: http://blog.sb2.fr/post/2008/12/01/HowTo-Get-Current-Online-Users-Count-and-Infos-with-ASPNET.aspx

Duplicate: [Get currently online users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454165/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-currently-online-users)